# How to pass content in Body for a POST request in Web Activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: salesforce, access-token, azure-data-factory, bearer-token

I want to generate a access token for salesforce using Azure data factory Web Activity. But I am getting error of grant type invalid or not supported.

URL:https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Header:Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

body:username=XXX&password=XXX&grant_type=password&client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX

Is there any information or content that i have missed in this?

anyone can help?

Comment: Can you show us the Screenshot of  Web acitivity Settings?

Comment: Thanks @JosephXu, But I have solve this, We have to pass Salesforce Security Token along with password.

Comment: OK, I'll use it as an answer. I've tried several times to repreat the problem, but it seems individual differences.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations you have solved the problem. The answer is that we have to pass Salesforce Security Token along with password.